# Rank of a locally free $\mathbb Z[G]$- module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $G$ be a finite group, $M$ a finitely generated $\mathbb Z[G]$-module so that the $\mathbb Z_p[G]$-module $M_p$ is free for all prime numbers $p$.

Here $\mathbb Z_p[G]=\mathbb Z_p\otimes_\mathbb Z\mathbb Z[G]$ and $M_p=\mathbb Z_p\otimes_\mathbb ZM$ where $\mathbb Z_p$ is the $p$-adic completion of $\mathbb Z$.

Then

> 1: Does $M$ embed in the tensor product via $x\mapsto 1\otimes x$ so that $\mathbb Q\otimes_\mathbb ZM=\mathbb QM$?
>
> 2: How do we show that $\mathbb Q\otimes_\mathbb ZM$ is a free $\mathbb Q[G]$-module of well defined rank?

If we define the rank of $M$ as the $\mathbb Q[G]$-rank of $\mathbb Q\otimes_\mathbb Z M$ then

> 3: How do we show that it's also the rank of $M_p$ over $\mathbb Z_p[G]$, for *all* $p$?

Thank you for your help.